# Facial expression val_accuracy does not improve

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am running te following code:

```
basemodel.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=25,validation_split=.1,callbacks=call_back)
```

But I get a result `Epoch 00014: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709`. I am not sure what is the issue there because I clearly see that my loss has decreased and my accuracy has increased.

This is the result

```
Epoch 1/25
909/909 [==============================] - 13s 6ms/step - loss: 1.6465 - accuracy: 0.3396 - val_loss: 1.4830 - val_accuracy: 0.4334

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.43344, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 2/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 1.3402 - accuracy: 0.4860 - val_loss: 1.3291 - val_accuracy: 0.4926

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy improved from 0.43344 to 0.49257, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 3/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 1.2050 - accuracy: 0.5418 - val_loss: 1.2769 - val_accuracy: 0.5025

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy improved from 0.49257 to 0.50248, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 4/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 1.1054 - accuracy: 0.5806 - val_loss: 1.1936 - val_accuracy: 0.5495

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy improved from 0.50248 to 0.54954, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 5/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 1.0190 - accuracy: 0.6159 - val_loss: 1.1535 - val_accuracy: 0.5551

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy improved from 0.54954 to 0.55511, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 6/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.9329 - accuracy: 0.6502 - val_loss: 1.1962 - val_accuracy: 0.5641

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy improved from 0.55511 to 0.56409, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 7/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8435 - accuracy: 0.6846 - val_loss: 1.1707 - val_accuracy: 0.5771

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy improved from 0.56409 to 0.57709, saving model to checkpoint/best_model.h5
Epoch 8/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.7527 - accuracy: 0.7201 - val_loss: 1.3817 - val_accuracy: 0.5545

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 9/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6633 - accuracy: 0.7576 - val_loss: 1.5021 - val_accuracy: 0.5207

Epoch 00009: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 10/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5865 - accuracy: 0.7874 - val_loss: 1.5610 - val_accuracy: 0.5721

Epoch 00010: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 11/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5154 - accuracy: 0.8097 - val_loss: 1.5723 - val_accuracy: 0.5430

Epoch 00011: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 12/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4540 - accuracy: 0.8333 - val_loss: 2.1641 - val_accuracy: 0.5650

Epoch 00012: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 13/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4106 - accuracy: 0.8511 - val_loss: 2.3236 - val_accuracy: 0.5322

Epoch 00013: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 14/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.3747 - accuracy: 0.8682 - val_loss: 1.8985 - val_accuracy: 0.5567

Epoch 00014: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 15/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.3480 - accuracy: 0.8768 - val_loss: 2.1689 - val_accuracy: 0.5505

Epoch 00015: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 16/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.3224 - accuracy: 0.8878 - val_loss: 2.0880 - val_accuracy: 0.5269

Epoch 00016: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 17/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.3157 - accuracy: 0.8912 - val_loss: 2.2746 - val_accuracy: 0.5328

Epoch 00017: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 18/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2960 - accuracy: 0.8992 - val_loss: 2.3014 - val_accuracy: 0.5582

Epoch 00018: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 19/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2961 - accuracy: 0.8998 - val_loss: 2.8190 - val_accuracy: 0.5399

Epoch 00019: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 20/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2945 - accuracy: 0.9016 - val_loss: 2.5621 - val_accuracy: 0.5495

Epoch 00020: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 21/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2772 - accuracy: 0.9075 - val_loss: 2.6602 - val_accuracy: 0.5402

Epoch 00021: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 22/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2857 - accuracy: 0.9070 - val_loss: 2.7156 - val_accuracy: 0.5381

Epoch 00022: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 23/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2767 - accuracy: 0.9098 - val_loss: 3.4705 - val_accuracy: 0.5291

Epoch 00023: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 24/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2725 - accuracy: 0.9100 - val_loss: 3.5462 - val_accuracy: 0.5706

Epoch 00024: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
Epoch 25/25
909/909 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2675 - accuracy: 0.9134 - val_loss: 2.3214 - val_accuracy: 0.5254

Epoch 00025: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.57709
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9d42d7afd0>
```

Below is a screenshot of my code:

My learning rate is .01.

```
basemodel.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=.01), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: Below is a screenshot of the rest of my code]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We do not accept code as images, you must include all code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case of overfitting/memorization of the training data by the model.

Change the Validation data and set  it to train data, you will see validation loss will also go down.

With the discussion That I had with you!! You had just 1000 data points and the model that you are building have 403,463 trainable parameters.

**Choices that you have**

1. Get more data
2. Use pretrained layers(this is known as transfer learning)
3. Use regularization parameter
4. Use Dropout
5. Use Batch normalization (Won't be very Effective)

Getting more data or using pre-trained layers will be highly effective in your case!!

Comment: You mean I change my data in my csv file?

Comment: Is it normal to overfit cause my results match what i want tho

Comment: It is bad to overfit on the data. It is like memorising the data instead of actual learning.

Comment: You can use dropping some of the neurons and regularisation function to learn better. Or try using more data to learn

Comment: I have 1000 data already, i guess it is related to my code?

Comment: The neural network you are training has a lot of parameters that needs to be trained!!
But you just have 1000 data points!! I would suggest you to use transfer learning. That Way you will be using meaningful.

Comment: You have 4,03,463 parameters to train!! and just have 1000 data points!! Your model will definitely Overfit and try to memorize the Train data.

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing, will try and see what is the final outcome